# How to add an optional type using Pick utility type?

Tags: typescript

I have a component for making HTTP requests, and one of the properties (`'address'`) should be optional, since I don't need it in one of the components where I call that function.

The way I did it before is to use the Partial utility type, but I want to be more specific and make a use of Pick.

Old version:

```
export type Trip = {
 address: string
 product: string
 no: number
 customer: string
 delievered: boolean
 name: string
 surname: string
}


export const usePostTrip = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const mutation = useMutation(
    async (data: Partial<Trip>) => {  // This is achieved with Partial
      const url = `${BASE_URL}/trip`
      return axios.post(url, data ).catch((e) => console.log(e.message))
    },
  )

  return mutation
}
```

Here is my current solution, which I believe is not the best one. Is there a better solution for this case?

```
export type Trip = {
 address: string
 product: string
 no: number
 customer: string
}

type tripWithoutAddress = Pick<
  Trip, 'product'| 'no'
>

type tripsWithAddress = Pick<
  Trip, 'product'| 'no' | 'address'
>

export const usePostTrip = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const mutation = useMutation(
    async (data: tripWithoutAddress | tripsWithAddress) => {   // This is achieved with Pick
      const url = `${BASE_URL}/trip`
      return axios.post(url, data).catch((e) => console.log(e.message))
    },
  )

  return mutation
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what's on Trip generally. "Without address" would more semantically be `Omit<Trip, "address">`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the answer.  Trip includes all types that api has. I will update my question

Comment: Really I suppose the question is: what's the point of the tripsWithAddress type, isn't that just Trip.

Comment: @jonrsharpe see my updated version for Trip

Answer (score 5):

I think [Jimmy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490642/438273) is good, but:

If you ever change the `address` property on `Trip` (e.g. from `string` to `number`), you'll also have to manually change the optional version in order to maintain type consistency.

By using `Pick` and `Partial`, you can [parametrically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_design) derive the type from `Trip`: any changes to the `address` property on `Trip` will automatically be changed in the derived type, too:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgSzFAvFA3gKCgQwCZ5wQDOxAXFMcIgHYDmA3NgMYCuVA9gLYRwVW1G2Ghwo1WXAEa8mUMHA55WzYP2oJ6TAL6ZMoSLERgA6gmAALAPJhgCDjRwAbAIIEipVFEtczAHnhIADRQAOT4hCTEIQB8UABkUAAKOHC2Tr6JCMwA1v5GwWFukTHRTJh4EMyOKdDM9lRQqoZIphbWtvZOrhGkTMAAdOHuxFAA9KOU6vRQAD5QrDQVAGYaEHhAA)

```ts
type Trip = {
 address: string;
 customer: string;
 no: number;
 product: string;
}

type TripWithOptionalAddress = Omit<Trip, 'address'> & Partial<Pick<Trip, 'address'>>;

declare const t: TripWithOptionalAddress;
t.address // string | undefined
```

Comment: After reviewing your updated question, it seems like you're learning about type utilities and are experimenting with `Pick` specifically. To just get `Trip` without address, it would simply be `Omit<Trip, 'address'>`. [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is just an inverted version of [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

Comment: thanks for the answer. You're right, I'm learning types, but also trying to find the best way target specific properties. If I understood correctly, Partial will make all properties optional,  so this is not we want. If we want more specific we make a use of Pick, when we know which type we need, and Omit will exclude the defined properties. 
In my case, type Trip has more than 100 properties and I can't exlcude so many properties using Omit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clearly stated in your question, but it sounds like you want a version of `Trip` where *only* the `address` property is optional, and the others remain required. This can be achieved by omitting the `address` property and then adding it back with an optional modifier by using an intersection type.

```
export type Trip = {
  address: string;
  product: string;
  no: number;
  customer: string;
};

export type TripWithOptionalAddress = Omit<Trip, "address"> & { address?: string; };

// All fields are required.
const trip: Trip = {
  address: "123 TypeScript Ave",
  product: "Stack Overflow",
  no: 123,
  customer: "Greg",
};

// `address` is missing.
const tripWithoutAddress: TripWithOptionalAddress = {
  product: "Stack Overflow",
  no: 123,
  customer: "Greg",
};

// `address` is still allowed, if present.
const tripWithAddress: TripWithOptionalAddress = trip;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
Type Trip has more than hundreds of properties.  As you can see in my provided example,  I didn't include the customer field as well.  Consider Trip to have more than 100 properties than you see here.
I updated Trip type

Answer (score 0):

Create type util and use it:

```
type TOptionalFields<T, U extends keyof T> = Omit<T, U> & Partial<Pick<T, U>>;

TOptionalFields<Trip, "address">
```